# NativeScript - Passing content from Parent to Child component

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I've been searching for this all over during the last 2 days so I decided to ask for help.
Imagine we have a parent component called ParentComponent and we have also a child component called SomeComponent.

SomeComponent template would be:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "SomeComponent",
    template: `
        <ActionBar title="TestApp">
        </ActionBar>
        <StackLayout style="margin-top:20;">
          <Label text="Somenthing on top"></Label>

            #CONTAINER CONTENT HERE#

          <Label text="Something in the bottom"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    `,

})
export class SomeComponent {}
```

..and ParentComponent template would be:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {SomeComponent} from "../some/where/...";

@Component({
    selector: "parent",
    template: `
        <SomeComponent>
            <Label text="Something here"></Label>
            <Label text="Something else here"></Label>
        </SomeComponent>
    `,

})
export class ParentComponent {}
```

Considering the aforementioned example, how can I get the content inside "< SomeComponent >" defined in my ParentComponent, to be displayed properly in the SomeComponent in the reserved "#CONTAINER CONTENT HERE#" area?

In theory it is as if I would end up with something like this:

```
<ActionBar title="TestApp">
</ActionBar>
<StackLayout style="margin-top:20;">
  <Label text="Somenthing on top"></Label>

    <Label text="Something here"></Label>
    <Label text="Something else here"></Label>

  <Label text="Something in the bottom"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

It looks like something pretty simple that I used to do in react native, that I can't get to work on NS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a ng-content tag to transclude the content from the parent container to the child. I believe all you need to add ng-content to your SomeContent component, which will then look like:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "SomeComponent",
    template: `
        <ActionBar title="TestApp">
        </ActionBar>
        <StackLayout style="margin-top:20;">
          <Label text="Somenthing on top"></Label>

            <ng-content></ng-content>

          <Label text="Something in the bottom"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    `,

})
export class SomeComponent {}
```

You can read more about transclusion here https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content

Also you can see a working example inside of the slides plugin I wrote  https://github.com/TheOriginalJosh/nativescript-ngx-slides/blob/master/slides/app/slides/slides.component.ts#L40

Comment: Yeah. I've tried exactly that but it didn't work. It might be something else that I'm doing that is in the way. At least now I know that this is the way of doing it. Tnx

Comment: I was not adding my component to "declarations":
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SomeComponent
  ],

Tnx @theOriginalJosh

Comment: Np, I forget that frequently myself.